# WebStorm and Optional Parameters in JSDoc Annotations

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc

I am working on a JavaScript project that runs in a special C environment. The environment has some functions that I need to use, and I wanted to add some dummy documentation files to provide code completion and type checking. Based on another answer on StackOverflow, I can do something like the code below to create a function just from annotations.

```
/**
 * @namespace Clib
 */
/**
 * @name Clib#test
 * @function
 * @param {String} [var=''] Some variable.
 */
```

Using JSDoc to generate HTML files works great, same with type checking, and code completion for the most part. However, WebStorm doesn't seem to understand optional parameters unless there is attached code.

From my example above, WebStorm gives a warning because it believes that

```
Clib.test();
```

is invalid because it is missing a parameter, even though I placed the parameter in [] and set a default value.

Now, if I were to put

```
Clib.test = function(var1){};
```

under the annotation, then WebStorm recognizes the optional parameter. Both it removes the warning from

```
Clib.test();
```

and shows that *var1* is optional in the code completion box.

I would rather not write quick mock-ups for each of these environment functions, if there's another way.

Is there something I am doing incorrectly with my annotations? Or is this a limitation of WebStorm?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're better off using Typescript. Webstorm understands Typescript definition files better.

Comment: nothing is wrong with your code. It's a bug in WebStorm JSDoc support - please vote for [WEB-8968](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8968)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I'll check out Typescript definition files. Never thought about using Typescript for this situation.

Comment: @lena Thanks for pointing out that bug. I voted for it. Good to know it wasn't a problem with my annotations.

Answer (score -1):

Check out Typescript Definition files support. Its where static analysis is heading for webstorm. In webstorm 7, Jetbrains is using it for static analysis, and not really relying much on jsdocs.